# Codeigniter Errors on Update Controller / Undefined Variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a simple crud application with Codeigniter.  I'm still trying to learn the framework.  But I'm getting an error in the Update Controller and can't seem to find it.

The Three Errors I'm getting are:

Severity: Warning
Message: Missing argument 1 for Customers::update_customer()
Filename: controllers/customers.php
Line Number: 67

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: id
Filename: controllers/customers.php
Line Number: 94

And this last one is a result of the form action.

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: id
Filename: views/edit_customer.php
Line Number: 16
" method="post">

---

CONTROLLER:

```
function update_customer($id){

    $data['success']=0;
    if($_POST){
        $data_customer=array(
            'first_name'=>$_POST['first_name'],
            'last_name'=>$_POST['last_name'],
            'phone'=>$_POST['phone'],
            'email'=>$_POST['email'],
            'website'=>$_POST['website'],
            'business_name'=>$_POST['business_name'],
            'business_add'=>$_POST['business_add'],
            'business_cityState'=>$_POST['business_cityState'],
            'cc_type'=>$_POST['cc_type'],
            'cc_number'=>$_POST['cc_number'],
            'cc_exp'=>$_POST['cc_exp'],
            'cc_cvd'=>$_POST['cc_cvd'],
            'billing_add'=>$_POST['billing_add'],
            'billing_zip'=>$_POST['billing_zip'],
            'package'=>$_POST['package'],
            'assigned_zip_code'=>$_POST['assigned_zip_code'],
            'active'=>1
        );
        $this->customer->update_customer($id,$data);
        $data['success']=1;
    }
    $data['customer']=$this->customer->get_customer($id);

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('edit_customer',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

MODEL:

```
function update_customer($id, $data){
    $this->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('customers', $data);
}
```

TOP OF THE VIEW:

```
    <?php if($success==1){ ?>
        <div class="successAlert">This customer has been updated.</div>
    <? } ?>

    <div class="mainForm">
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

        <form action="<?=base_url()?>customers/update_customer/<?=$customer['id']?>" method="post">

            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label> 
            <input type="input" name="first_name" value="" /><br />
            <hr>
```

Comment: pretty self explanatory.  your not loading the id variable?  are you trying to pull it from the uri segment?  whats the code for get_customer()?  and how does it intitally get the id on first page load.

Comment: Also $_POST is a global variable that will always exists, although it may be empty, your if statement will always be true.  Instead of if($_POST) try array_key_exists($key, $_POST).  You should also look into the form validation class available to you from codeigniter if you want to build a robust application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. You're cloning an array key for key: bad

Why bother constructing the `$data_customer` array like this? The end result looks identical to `$_POST` anyway with the exception of the added `'active'` key.

If you really want to clone the array, just write:

```
$data_customer = $_POST;
$data_customer['active'] = 1;
```

This is, of course, a lot more resistant to changes in the values you are submitting to the server too. If you decide to send, for instance, the middle name in the future, it requires zero maintenance.

### 2. `if($_POST)`...

`if($_POST)` will always return `TRUE` because `$_POST` is a global, the `if` will *always* execute. You'd be better to use CodeIgniter's `$this->input->post()`, which returns `FALSE` if a the user did not submit post data.

### 3. Your Errors

You need to pass an `id` into the `update_customer()` function. This can be accomplished by sending the POST request to `http://localhost/your_app/customers/update_customer/5`, as an example.

Or, you could attach the id as a hidden value in the form using `<input type='hidden' name='id' value='5'/>` and then retrieve it in the `$this->input->post()` array as well and remove the `$id` parameter from `update_customer($id)`.

That will clear up your first two errors.

The last error is occurring in your view because `$customer` does not contain an index of `id`. Inspect the response from `$this->customer->get_customer($id)` using `var_dump()` to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not passing an  $id paramater to your update() function

Comment: when you call function from url,pass an id of customer, example: yourdomain.com/get_customer/1